# Clojure 1.4 seems to not support amap without type hints

Tags: clojure

I am working through [The Joy of Clojure](http://joyofclojure.com/) (which I understand was written for Clojure 1.2) and I'm trying to understand something about `amap` and related functions.

The following code doesn't work in Clojure 1.4 without type hints:

```lisp
(defn asum-sq [xs]
  (let [dbl (amap xs i ret
                 (* (aget xs i)
                    (aget xs i)))]
    (areduce dbl i ret 0.0
      (+ ret (aget dbl i)))))
```

REPL:

```
user=> (asum-sq (float-array [1 2 3 4]))
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: aset clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:80)
```

Version with type hints added works:

```lisp
(defn ^Double asum-sq [^floats xs]
  (let [^floats dbl (amap xs i ret
                       (* (aget xs i)
                          (aget xs i)))]
    (areduce dbl i ret 0.0
      (+ ret (aget dbl i)))))
```

REPL:

```
user=> (asum-sq (float-array [1 2 3 4]))
30.0
```

I'm having a hard time finding information on this issue.  When exactly was this breaking change introduced?  Or am I understanding this wrongly?

Comment: Number handling was changed quite a bit in 1.3. Information is here: http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Documentation+for+1.3+Numerics

Comment: Removed my earlier comment. The linked documentation does not specifically address the non-backwards compatible changes apparently(?) made to `amap` in 1.3(?)

Comment: Right, I was just trying to point you in the general direction. Joy of Clojure code holds up pretty well in most cases that I've run into, but there are a few that are obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The breaking change is that too generic overloads of both `RT/aget` and `RT/aset` got removed.

`a[gs]et` is there for when you want raw speed (otherwise you would `seq` or `vec` the array) and lack of proper hinting was causing them to silently takes a sloooow path.